# For Loop in SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantics, semantic-web, dbpedia

I have a simple problem. When I run this query on DBpedia SPARQL endpoint, I get a list of 5 movies URIs:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 

select ?film {
?film rdf:type <http://schema.org/Movie>.

}
limit 5
```

I am trying to access to all predicates and objects of every movie in the list. I tried this but it did not work.

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 

select ?film ?p ?o {
?film rdf:type <http://schema.org/Movie>;
      ?p ?o.
}
group by ?film
limit 5
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SPARQL is recursive by nature so no for loops required. This means, in relation to your 2nd example, it will match all predicates and objects where film is a type of movie. I believe you may be thinking your query is not working when it actually is but the limit on the amount of answers being returned is masking this.

I suggest for retrieving a single film -

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
select ?s ?o ?o where {
 ?s ?p ?o .
 FILTER (?s = ?film)
 {
  select ?film {
   ?film rdf:type <http://schema.org/Movie> .
  }
  group by ?film
  limit 1
 }
}
```

Comment: A few notes: (i) I'm pretty sure you want "select ?s ?p ?o", not "select ?s ?o ?o". (ii) You could eliminate the filter (which could be inefficient if the query engine is naive), by using the same variable.  I.e., make the subquery be "{ select ?s { ?s rdf:type ... ".  (iii) There's no need for "group by" in the subquery. (iv) The limit should be 5, not 1 (but OP needs to set that to whatever OP needs, so that's not so important).